# How do I Use AutoCompleteTextView and populate it with data from a web API?

Tags: android, networking, filter, autocompletetextview

I want to use an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my activity and populate the data as the user types by querying a web API.  How do I go about doing this?

Do I create a new class and override `AutoCompleteTextView.performFiltering`, or do I use a custom list adapter and provide a custom `android.widget.Filter` that overrides performFiltering?

Or is there a better way to obtain my end goal?

I've done something somewhat similar, but it was for the Quick Search box and it involved implementing a service, but I believe that's not what I want to do here.

Comment: a terrific link for future viewers :) : http://makovkastar.github.io/blog/2014/04/12/android-autocompletetextview-with-suggestions-from-a-web-service/

Comment: Please see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313126/3904109

Answer (score 109, accepted):

I came up with a solution, I don't know if it is the best solution, but it appears to work very well.  What I did was created a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter.  In the custom adapter I overrode getFilter and created my own Filter class that overrides performFiltering.  This starts a new thread so it doesn't interrupt the UI.  Below is a barebones example.

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private AutoCompleteTextView style;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        style = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.style);
        adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line); 
        style.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

AutoCompleteAdapter.java

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Style> implements Filterable {
    private ArrayList<Style> mData;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mData = new ArrayList<Style>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Style getItem(int index) {
        return mData.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null) {
                    // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and returns an ArrayList<Style>
                    StyleFetcher fetcher = new StyleFetcher();
                    try {
                        mData = fetcher.retrieveResults(constraint.toString());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("myException", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults object
                    filterResults.values = mData;
                    filterResults.count = mData.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint, FilterResults results) {
                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good solution - exactly what I needed. If I might ask though... you return a style to your simple_dropdown_item_1line layout. How do you retrieve an appropriate value from your Style class? For me, it's a class I created and I want the text value getStyleName to display in my list item, but it simple displays the name of the class.

Comment: @bugfixr Add a public toString method on your class.  In my example it was:

    public String toString() { return name; }

Comment: I always get null as constraint variable. What i'm doing wrong ? I'm using Honeycomb as device

Comment: @Alex how did you solve your problem with the constraint always null?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating an anonymous class as well as create a new instance inside a getter if you can help it. Create the class once (maybe as inner), instantiate it as few times in the lifecycle as possible. Simply return the reference in the getter.

Comment: Be careful with the notifyDataSetInvalidated() call. That means that subsequently the adapter cant be used.

Comment: For those coming here from Google and having same problem as @bugfixr, the proper solution is to override `convertResultToString(Object resultValue)` in the `Filter`

Comment: But this is doing network request in same thread, is the `performFiltering` method running in non-UI thread?

Comment: How did you create the Style class? I found nothing after searching google

Comment: @AJ. Thanks for the answer. As the answer is 6 years old, I wonder if it is still the best practice or there is a new and better way to implement an auto-complete element.

Comment: @Tohid This is still the best answer, only one thing can be added to this. That is a delayed handler could be used to trigger the API call. As shown here: https://www.truiton.com/2018/06/android-autocompletetextview-suggestions-from-webservice-call/

Answer (score 7):

Expanding on [AJ.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051180/2038544)'s answer above, the following custom adapter includes the handling of the server requests and json parsing as well:

```
class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable
{
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private final String server = "http://myserver/script.php?query=";

    AutoCompleteAdapter (@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource)
    {
        super (context, resource);
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem (int position)
    {
        return data.get (position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null)
                {
                    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
                    InputStream input = null;
                    try
                    {
                        URL url = new URL (server + constraint.toString());
                        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        input = conn.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader (input, "UTF-8");
                        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader (reader, 8192);
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
                        {
                            builder.append (line);
                        }
                        JSONArray terms = new JSONArray (builder.toString());
                        ArrayList<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int ind = 0; ind < terms.length(); ind++)
                        {
                            String term = terms.getString (ind);
                            suggestions.add (term);
                        }
                        results.values = suggestions;
                        results.count = suggestions.size();
                        data = suggestions;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (input != null)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                input.close();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if (conn != null) conn.disconnect();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults (CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0)
                {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        };
    }
```

and use it the same way:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById (R.id.style);
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter (this, layout); 
        textView.setAdapter (adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Chu: To customize how the view looks and get more control over unwrapping the object, do the following...

```
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView originalView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent); // Get the original view

        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);

        // Start tweaking
        view.setText(originalView.getText());
        view.setTextColor(R.color.black);  // also useful if you have a color scheme that makes the text show up white
        view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 10); // override the text size
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private AutoCompleteUserAdapter userAdapter;
private AutoCompleteTextView actvName;
private ArrayList<SearchUserItem> arrayList;

actvName = findViewById(R.id.actvName);

actvName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        actvName.setText(userAdapter.getItemNameAtPosition(position));
        actvName.setSelection(actvName.getText().toString().trim().length());
    }
});

actvName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (actvName.isPerformingCompletion()) {
            // An item has been selected from the list. Ignore.
        } else {
            if (s.toString().toLowerCase().trim().length() >= 2) {
                getUserList(s.toString().toLowerCase().trim());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});

private void getUserList(String searchText) {
    //Add data to your list after success of API call
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.addAll(YOUR_LIST);
    userAdapter = new AutoCompleteUserAdapter(context, R.layout.row_user, arrayList);
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            actvName.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            actvName.showDropDown();
        }
    });        
}
```

**AutoCompleteUserAdapter**

```
/**
 * Created by Ketan Ramani on 11/07/2019.
 */
public class AutoCompleteUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SearchUserItem> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<SearchUserItem> arrayList;

    public AutoCompleteUserAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<SearchUserItem> arrayList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, arrayList);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }

            SearchUserItem model = arrayList.get(position);

            AppCompatTextView tvUserName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUserName);
            tvUserName.setText(model.getFullname());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public String getItemNameAtPosition(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position).getName();
    }

    public String getItemIDAtPosition(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position).getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: up vote for actvName.isPerformingCompletion() that saved my handling.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Kotlin version of the Adapter Class that loads data from a local database via Room:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import android.widget.Filterable
import android.widget.TextView
import ...MyFinderDatabase
import ...R
import ...model.SearchResult

class SearchCompleteAdapter(context: Context, val resourceId: Int): ArrayAdapter<SearchResult>(context, resourceId), Filterable {
    private val results = mutableListOf<SearchResult>()

    override fun getCount() = results.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = results[position]

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourceId, parent, false)
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.autocomplete_name)
        textView.text = getItem(position).fullName
        return view
    }

    override fun getFilter() = object : Filter(){
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filterResults = FilterResults()
            val db = MyRoomDatabase.getDatabase(context.applicationContext)
            val dbResults = db.resultDao().findWithNameLike(String.format("%%%s%%", constraint.toString()))
            filterResults.values = dbResults
            filterResults.count = dbResults.size
            results.clear()
            results.addAll(dbResults)
            return filterResults
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            if((results != null) && (results.count > 0)){
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            else{
                notifyDataSetInvalidated()
            }
        }

        override fun convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence {
            val searchResult = resultValue as SearchResult
            return searchResult.fullName
        }
    }
}
```

DAO method definition:

```
    @Query("select * from SearchResult where full_name like :name and type = 'USER_TYPE'")
fun findWithNameLike(name: String): List<SearchResult>
```

Comment: Thanks! You just saved me a couple of hours =)