# Android autocomplete EditText from server

Tags: android, autocomplete

I want to implement an Autocomplete mechanism for an EditText field, but the list of autocomplete comes from the server.
I looked into AutoCompleteTextView but it only supports fixed strings by default.

I'm just talking about the UI. I'll be issuing a http request to my webserver and getting the JSON result back. When do I fire the request and how do I plug it into the UI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you could use the AutoCompleteTextView, like in this example:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

...but in order to use your server, you'll have to tweak your Adapter. That's what it's for :)

**EDIT: ** Here's a nice example:
[How do I Use AutoCompleteTextView and populate it with data from a web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023645/how-do-i-use-autocompletetextview-and-populate-it-with-data-from-a-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of service offers your server. For example if it is a web server, you should execute a http request.

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear enough. I'm just talking about the UI. I'll be issuing a http request to my webserver and getting the JSON result back. When do I fire the request and how do I plug it into the UI?

Comment: I am also facing similar issue..please post the code if someone found a solution