# Android : popup the words as typing in google browser when typing in edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a list of words called keywords stored in array list. I want the appropriate words from it to pop up when typing same word in edit text as we see when typing in google browser. How to achieve it?

Comment: Use **AutoCompleteTextView**: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Use AutoCompleteTextView and populate it with data from a web API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023645/how-do-i-use-autocompletetextview-and-populate-it-with-data-from-a-web-api)